# Grouping on an attribute using itertools.groupby

Tags: python

I have a list of instances of the class 'Chromosome'.

The list is sorted on the Chromosome attribute 'equation'

I now want to remove instances where the attribute 'equation' is the same, leaving only one.

I don't know how to pass the key, ie the ?, so that it groups on 'equation'.

```
b = [a for a,b in groupby(list, ?)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import operator

[a for a, b in groupby(thelist, operator.attrgetter('equation')]
```

Btw, don't use builtin type names (such as `list`, `file`, etc) for your own identifiers, it's a confusing and best-avoided practice that will eventually byte you with peculiar bugs unless you wean yourself off it (i.e one day you'll be maintaining your code, and find yourself using `list(sometuple)` to make a list out of some tuple, or the like... and get weird errors if you've used `list` to mean something different than `list` in this scope!-).

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do it:

```
b = [a for a,b in groupby(list, key=lambda a: a.equation)]
```